# Word for government sponsored manipulation of records and evidences

Tags: word-request

Something **not done for profit** but to **keep the public under dark**.

---

Edit: Not exactly what I was looking for but the word "***covert***" or its synonyms "***clandestine***" or "***surreptitious***" will do for now. Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any examples of what you describe.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? Right now, it's very vague. The two suggestions so far, covert and fraud, are extremely different in meaning.

Comment: smacks of political intrigue, iron-curtain stuff. Can't think of a simple word for it, but not voting to close it.

Comment: @Karen I couldn't clarify because I myself didn't know what exactly was I looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [**covert**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/covert):

> 1) concealed, hidden, disguised, or surreptitious   ⇒ "a covert threat"

though it is not specific to the government, but is often used that way.

> The Watergate break in was a **covert** operation.

Answer (score 1):

Two words that come to mind are "fraud"

> a person or thing intended to deceive others, typically by unjustifiably claiming or being credited with accomplishments or qualities

And "cover-up"

> an attempt to prevent people's discovering the truth about a serious mistake or crime.

I don't think there is a word that is specific to the government doing this, however you could say "government fraud" or "government cover-up".